# How can I load Java EE application dependency from WildFly modules

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-9

I am migrating my JBoss from 4.0.5 to WildFly 9.0.2 release, and my application has some dependency from `JRE/lib/rt.jar`, but when I deploy that application on WildFly, application gives error like ClassNotFoundException. If I add `rt.jar` as dependency in lib directory then application works.

So does anyone knows how to overcome from this problem.

Eg.

`javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.class` which is available in `rt.jar`.

Comment: Could you share log file of WildFly? and Have you ever check JRE libraries on build path of your project?

Comment: Please find a like to download log file.

[Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UHhxI12LRUWXAzLVREQ2NLSmM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you add apache xerces on your WildFly as a module? I think that if you add as a module, exception will be solved. Also, I guess you controlled JRE library on build path of your project.

Comment: After adding your suggestion I am getting one more exception, Please have a look in attached link [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UHhxI12LRUWXAzLVREQ2NLSmM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I checked and made comparison but both files are same. Given exception from WildFly is same, too. Are you sure that you add apache xerces as a module? Could you update your question that shows module definition on WildFly?

Comment: Sorry Sevan, I forgot to update the link, Here is the actual file link [Click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UHhxI12LRUaFpoekVhUWFIWWs/view)

Comment: Did you add "Dependencies: javax.api" to MANIFEST.MF of your war/ear archive?

Comment: I have added the Dependencies in MANIFEST.MF too, but still the same issue, If I add any other extension then also I am getting the same Failed to load module error, **xerces** this module already has a dependency for javax.api.

Comment: As a general rule you do not need any XML jars (such as xerces, xalan or xml-apis) in your deployments. In fact their very presence can cause weird errors such as yours. Please check that your deployed app contains **none** of these artifacts. And you certainly do not need to specify WildFly module dependencies.

Comment: Hi, I have added the sample application on git hub so you can also reproduce the same issue on your local too. [GitHub](https://github.com/alpesh-jikadra/wildfly9-issues-examples)